# Firebase realtime database app freeze when back to online after to do many operation while offline

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app using firebase realtime database and I setPersistenceEnabled(true) to make it still work when device goes offline. Everything is ok when device offline, every operation like add, change, and remove data can work fine.

Problem come when device come back online after do too many operation for example delete much data when offline. After I see many data in my realtime database was delete simultaneously, I cannot do operation like add and change data for several times (5-10 minute) and it depend on how much data I was delete when offline. I can only see my add and change operation after that time.

My question is how many operation firebase can handle when offline and make it still smooth when it come back online, so my app not like freeze for several time when user add and change another data?, or

is there any trick to make it smooth when transition from offline to online when I have many operation to do in offline mode?

below is my code to update my data before I delete it, and when offline my app can run this block of code until 100 times for example in 1 hour:

```
public void ritase(String number){                                       
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/vehicles/").child(number);

    HashMap<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    childUpdates.put("ritase/from", from);
    childUpdates.put("ritase/to", to);
    childUpdates.put("ritase/accept", accept);
    childUpdates.put("ritase/userid", userid);
    childUpdates.put("ritase/passenger", passenger);
    childUpdates.put("ritase/stat", 1);
    childUpdates.put("ritase/time_out", time);
    childUpdates.put("trips/content/time_out", time);
    childUpdates.put("trips/content/stat", 1);

    ref.updateChildren(childUpdates);
    ref.removeValue();                                                      
}
```

and after my app back to online again, below block of code operation was stuck for several minutes. Stuck here means I cannot see the change immediately in my app:

```
Public void updateStatus(String number){                                   
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/vehicles/").child(number); 
    HashMap<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    childUpdates.put("driver/name", name);
    childUpdates.put("driver/nip", nip);

    if (PrefHelper.getPref(context,VarConstant.ISBARCODE) == "true") {
        childUpdates.put("is_barcode", 1);
    } else {
        childUpdates.put("is_barcode", 0);
    }

    childUpdates.put("position/content/location", location);
    childUpdates.put("position/content/time_in", time);
    childUpdates.put("position/content/time_out", 0);
    childUpdates.put("position/content/stat", 0);
    childUpdates.put("position/content/username", username);

    int status;

    if (PrefHelper.getPref(context, VarConstant.TYPE).contains(VarConstant.PERIMETER)) {
        status = 0;
        childUpdates.put("trips/content/status", status);
        childUpdates.put("trips/content/time_start", 0);
        childUpdates.put("trips/content/time_stop", 0);
    } else {
        status = 2;
        childUpdates.put("trips/content/status", status);
        childUpdates.put("trips/content/time_start", time);
        childUpdates.put("trips/content/time_stop", time);
    }

    ref.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

}

I also try to use completion listener for removeValue(), but it fire very late even in firebase realtime database the data was delete.

Comment: What do you mean through `many operations`? How many?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo i just did delete operation for 100 different data...and after i connect to internet, i think it queue my delete operation to server and after that every another operation like add, change, and delete must wait for 100 delete operation to complete. The weird thing is my 100 data was delete simultaneously in my realtime database, but the completion listener is come to late when i checked

Comment: I don't know of any hard-coded limit to the queue of pending write operations. Please update your question to include the [minimal, complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen i just update my question...

Comment: The results from the calls to `ref.updateChildren(childUpdates)` and `ref.removeValue(); ` should be immediately available locally, since Firebase fires local events without waiting for a server response. But as the write queue grows, it may start taking longer, since the client has to apply all updates in turn. It should however never drop any of these updates. So if it just takes longer as you have more pending writes, that sounds as if it's working as intended.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can firebase immediately show my change in updateStatus() method locally while wait it turn when I am online after offline for a long time... because it seems like my app getting freeze and any add or update data seems like wait for its turn before show up.

Comment: When specifically does your app freeze? Is it when you write data (e.g. call `ritase`)? Or when you attach a new listener? Or when you restart the app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when i call updateStatus(). but it freeze only if I just connected to internet and have a lot of pending ritase() when offline.

Comment: That is expected. When you restart the app, it applies the queue of pending writes to its local snapshot of the data it has read before. The performance of this operation is linear to the length of the queue of pending writes.

Answer (score 0):

When you use disk persistence, Firebase stores two types of data on disk:

1. A cache of recently read data.
2. A queue of pending writes.

It also keeps an in-memory copy of all active data, which means: any data that you're currently listening for. In this in-memory copy, the pending writes are applied to the data.

When you restart your app and attach a listener, Firebase loads the cached data and applies any pending writes it has. This process has linear performance, and can be quite slow due to the hashing algorithm used.

This means that restarting an app that has a lot of cached data with many pending writes can indeed take some time. This is expected behavior.

To reduce the startup time, limit the amount of data you keep offline, and limit the number of pending writes.

Comment: can I control how much offline pending write to push to firebase when I getting online?... for example just 10 pending write every 1 minute to make my app not getting slow

Comment: There is no API to control this. Most Firebase apps write fairly limited amounts of data, compared the amount they read. To be honest, if you're perceiving significant slowdown because of these writes, I'd recommend reducing how much data you write. If that is not possible, Firebase might not be a good fit for your use-case.